# variable regex test in dash?

Tags: variable, test, dash

I got plenty possible variables in a form of `[a-z][0-9]`, eg 1 letter and 1 number.
Is there a way to test them in dash? Something like:

```
myvar=o7
if [ $myvar=o[0-4] ]; then 
"do this"
elif [ $myvar=o[5-7] ]; then
"do that"
fi
```

Thx in advance:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need regular expressions for what you're wanting to do:

```bsh
case $myvar in
    o[0-4])
        echo 'do this'
        ;;
    o[5-7])
        echo 'do that'
        ;;
    *)
        echo 'unsupported case'
esac
```

or, more compactly,

```bsh
case $myvar in
    o[0-4]) echo 'do this' ;;
    o[5-7]) echo 'do that' ;;
    *)      echo 'unsupported case'
esac
```

Here, the value `$myvar` is matched against each given  case label in turn, and the code corresponding to the first label that matches will be executed.  The `;;` delimits the code of a label from the next label (which means that the last label does not *need* `;;` at the end before `esac`).

Each label is a globbing pattern on the form `pattern)` or `(pattern)`, not a regular expression.

The `case...esac` structure provides a standard and compact way of doing something that could also be written like

```bsh
if [[ $myvar == o[0-4] ]]; then
    echo 'do this'
elif [[ $myvar == o[5-7] ]]; then
    echo 'do that'
else
    echo 'unsupported case'
fi
```

in `bash` and similar shells.